# Saving data temporarily when testing scripts

Tags: python

I wrote a script that will read data from a large database and save it as a list of lists:

```
data = [[entry1, entry2], [entry1, entry2], ...]
```

Because the database that the script reads from is very big, it takes a while to generate a data list like this. However, I am performing analysis on this data list and currently writing functions which will be used on the data list. Unfortunately, I am still in the test stage so not all the functions that I write will work. It is painful to load the script and generate a data list every time that I test functions on it.

Is there a way to temporarily store the data list somewhere in Python so that I can directly test the new functions on this data list, without having to generate the data list all over again?

Comment: One option for this is called `pickling`.  There are probably better ways to do this, but pickling is pretty easy to implement (although it's been a while since I've worked in python...) https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: Ah, pickling will only help you avoid network I/Os.  If you are running and interactive python prompt you could keep your data list in memory (supposing it fits in RAM) and perform operations on it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider saving your data to a temporary file.

```
f = open('data.txt','w')
f.writelines(data)
f.close()
```